# How to mail a md5 password in php?

Tags: php, email, passwords, md5

i am using md5 for passwords and storing it in MySQL.I don't have problems logging in but what i need is, i want to mail the exact password which user enters during registration to his mail id.how can i get back the password and send it to mail?

```
// username and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];
// encrypt password
$encrypted_mypassword=md5($mypassword);
```

Comment: It is the point of hashing, that the cleartext is **not** recoverable. But since you still use MD5, any google for 'MD5 aabbcc...nn' will most likely find an equivalent password for you ;-)

Comment: 1. MD5 has been obsolete for a while now. Why are you using it? 2. MD5 is a hashing algorithm. That means it is *one way*. You can't get it back. 3. Reversing passwords is a bad practice. Let a user reset their password instead.

Comment: You definitely do not want to be emailing passwords around.

Comment: @Eugen Rieck First of all thanks for the response.
Actually i know how to get it from a website but what i want is, to mail the users username and password to his mail id

Comment: @John Conde
User can reset the password but don't we need to send the password to user?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth I understood why we shouldn't send password to users. but my client requirement is, once after successful registration user have to receive a mail containing his username and password

Comment: @JRameshFernandez Nope. Send them a temporary password, or better yet, a unique url where they can reset it. That takes the responsibility for it out of your hand (beyond storage).

Comment: @JRameshFernandez: I would say that it's your responsibility to convince your client that their requirement is totally inappropriate...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth i will try convincing the client.. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question directly, you can send the user's "initial password" this way (assuming MD5 - but the logic is the same no matter what hashing algorithm you use).

```
$seed_password = $_POST['initial_password'];  // Save the user's selected password to this variable.
$hash_password = md5($seed_password); // This variable will now hold your hashed password.

// Save the $hash_password to the database.
#  YOUR CODE HERE

// Email the Seed Password (in the simplest manner possible).
mail('target@email.com' , 'Your new password' , 'Your new password is '. $seed_password);
```

This will email the value of the password before hashing.  Meanwhile, the hashed password will be stored in your database.

Now - when your user logs in, you're going to have to take the password they enter and HASH it before *comparing* it with the hashed value in your database.

Comment: Note that I'm assuming you're getting the password using $_POST, but of course you can fill that variable with the password any way you get it - whether POSTed or generated automatically.

Comment: Really i appreciate the way you answered my question. this is the exact answer i wanted. even though i understood the risks of sending cleartext password. but i just asked it for the client requirement. i will try convincing the client regarding this. thank you so much for your valuable responses

Comment: Actually i didn't change. I thought its like liking in facebook so i liked both the answers. just now i realised its not alike facebook's like button. your answer is what i exactly expected. thank you again

Comment: A pleasure to help :)

Answer (score 2):

As everyone is pointing out, using md5 is not a good idea at all.  Think about using something like bcrypt which is relatively straight forward to implement with PHP. Ensure you use a random salt, and implement it properly to ensure it's doing what you are assuming it's doing.  This is a good guide that you can play with https://gist.github.com/marcoarment/1053158.

Rather than sending a user their password, which is a bad option on several levels, you might consider sending them a randomly generated hash that brings them to your application where they can simply reset their password altogether by themselves.

Sending mail in PHP can be a simple process. You can refer to this http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php. There are several good examples.  For sending transactional mail that will be more unlikely to end up in spam you might consider a service such as http://postmarkapp.com.

Comment: i know how to send mail in php. and am sending the username and password but that password is hash which i don't want to be like.

Comment: No user of your application will appreciate getting a cleartext password in their inbox. Hypothetically imagine I check my non-ssl email account on public wifi with zerocool sniffing around and he sees the contents of the message?  Imagine I'm somewhat of a saavy web user and I see you have my password in cleartext? I'll assume you are storing it in cleartext and will avoid whatever service you offer like the plague.  No excuses, it's bad practice and you will be endangering your users unnecessarily.

Comment: I get everyone's point, but that's not the question.  See my answer to the question you actually asked.

Comment: @cjaredrun Thanks a lot. I understood it and u made it very clear too

Answer (score 0):

if your string is converted to md5 string, you never get it back anymore, but you can try the md5 decrypter on the web but it doesn't 100% work as expected. try to reset with new password, i think it's more secure.